# SQL Server precision/scale when multiplying numeric(32,9) columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with scale of numeric column.

We are multiplying two `numeric(32,9)` columns (`QUANTITY` and `SPLIT`) and the result is always returned as `numeric(32,6)`.

How can I get the result to be as `decimal(32,9)`?

```
select
    t1.QUANTITY,
    t1.[TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX],
    t2.SPLIT,
    (t1.QUANTITY * t2.SPLIT) as QUANTITY2,
    (t1.[TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX] * t2.SPLIT) as TURNOVER_WITHOUT_TAX2
from 
    SalesPlan t1
right join
    DailyDistr t2 on t1.WEEK = t2.WEEK 
where 
    (t1.[TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX]*t2.SPLIT) > 0
```

The result

```
    QUANTITY    TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX    SPLIT   QUANTITY2   TURNOVER_WITHOUT_TAX2
0.210724257 9.770862333 0.300000000000  0.063217    2.931259
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication of both numbers results in a type of `numeric(65, 18)`.  Given the rules of the numeric type for multiplication and division as described in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the resulting scale of the product converted to 6.  The is because the integral portion is 45 digits and that causes the results to be converted to be cast as (38, 6).

To get around this restriction, I recast the columns to a scale that would result in the integral part being less than 32, but still big enough so that the scale wouldn't get reduced by rules applied when the integral portion is less than 32.  So in the end, I cast both numbers to *numeric(32,18)*, and then cast the product down to *numeric(32,9)*.

Casting the numbers to numeric(32,17) might have satisfied the requirement that the integral portion be less than 32, but then the scale would've been reduced by the rule `38 - (precision - scale)` => `38 - (65-34)` = a scale of 7.

```
SELECT t1.QUANTITY,
  , t1.[TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX]
  , t2.SPLIT
  , CAST(CAST(QUANTITY AS numeric(32, 18)) * CAST(SPLIT AS numeric(32,18)) 
        AS numeric(32, 9)) [QUANTITY2]
  , CAST(CAST([TURNOVER WITHOUT TAX] AS numeric(32, 18)) * CAST(SPLIT AS numeric(32,18)) 
        AS numeric(32, 9)) [TURNOVER_WITHOUT_TAX2]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the result to be as decimal(32,9)?

According to this Reference: [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Operation | Result precision | Result scale *
--------- | ---------------- | --------------
e1 * e2   | p1 + p2 + 1      |  s1 + s2
```

> The result precision and scale have an **absolute maximum of 38**. When a result precision is greater than 38, **it's reduced to 38**, and the
>   corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the
>   integral part of a result. In some cases such as multiplication or
>   division, scale factor won't be reduced, to maintain decimal
>   precision, although the overflow error can be raised.
>
> In multiplication and division operations, we need precision - scale
>   places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be
>   reduced using the following rules:
>
> 1. The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 - (precision-scale)) if the integral part is less than 32, because it
>      can't be greater than 38 - (precision-scale). Result might be rounded
>      in this case.
> 2. The scale won't be changed if it's less than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might be raised
>      if it can't fit into decimal(38, scale)
> 3. The scale will be set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and
>      scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result
>      might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the overflow error will be
>      thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32 digits.

The third point exactly describes the issue you are have encountered.

And actual example from the reference:

```
select 
cast(0.0000009000 as decimal(30,10)) 
* cast(1.0000000000 as decimal(30,10)) 
-- results as
[decimal(38, 6)]
```

In this case precision is 61, and scale is 20. Scale is greater than 6 and integral part (`precision-scale = 41`) is greater than 32. This case is case (3) in multiplication rules and result type is `decimal(38,6)`.